# Does the implicit function theorem hold for discontinuously differentiable functions?

Tags: implicit-function-theorem

[Wikipedia's statement of the implicit function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) requires that the original function

be continuously differentiable. $\:$ Is it known whether or not that condition can be removed?

If it can't be completely removed, can it be replaced with

"differentiable function whose derivative is bounded"?

Comment: Highly related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/75049/does-the-inverse-function-theorem-hold-for-everywhere-differentiable-maps

Comment: I have cross-posted this [to mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/182030/5810). $\;$